# Linking Local files among each other via a href

Tags: html, css

enter image description here[image][image]
I am trying to link between the various files to be able to jump back and forth for navigation. I am trying to go from index.html to ConversionsPage.html which i can do. However from ConversionsPage.html I can not get to any of the other pages within that same folder or back to index.html

```
 <a href="Pages/ConversionsPage.html" >Assignment Number 1 </br> is what i 
 used to get to the conversions page. From the conversions page i am trying 
 to go to ConvertFahrenheitToCelsius.html and then from there have a return 
 to the main conversions page.
  <a href="Pages/ConversionsPage.html" >Return to Conversions Page</br>
```

I keep getting an error that it is not found or deleted. """""""

Comment: Show us how you are trying to navigate.

Comment: index.html > ConversionsPage.html > All the html files in same folder as conversions page > back to Conversions page. Then on the Conversions page also have a way back to index.html not sure if that helps

Comment: It would be great if you have a working example which replicate this issue on sites like jsfiddle.

Comment: @AndrewRibicki From which page is the HTML that you have posted? If it is from any of the pages within the "Pages" folder, the href should be simply `href="ConversionsPage.html"` - without the `Pages/`.

Comment: Trying to go from ConversionsPage.html back to index.html which should be above it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your hrefs don't properly account for the folder structure. You just need to remove the directory from the hrefs between files in Pages.

For example, in ConversionsPage.html

```
<a href="ConvertGallonsToLiters.html">Gallons to Liters</a>
```

Comment: Sweet, i knew it was something stupid simple the more i kept looking at it the more it got worse. How would i go about going back from those to index.html?

Comment: still having issues going from ConvertFahrenheitToCelsius back up to Index.html

Comment: You'll need to add the "parent directory" (`../`) prefix to the href URL. Like `<a href="../Index.html">Back to Index</a>`.